# Semantic UI not organizing grids

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I'm working on a project based on Semantic UI and using it's grid system. The fist part of code using grids works fine:

```
<div className='ui grid fluid container'>
  <div className='stackable six wide column' id='logo'>
    <img src='/images/home/icone-logo.svg' />
  </div>
  <div className='twelve wide mobile nine wide tablet nine wide computer column' id='nome'>
    <img src='/images/home/nome-logo.svg' />
    <br />
    <br />
    <span id='slogan'>Um sistema de estudo feito para você</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

On the second part, the element loads the ui and grid styles but not the column style that should organize it.

```
<div className='ui grid fluid container'>
  <div className='four wide cloumn'>
    <img src="/images/home/ALUNO.svg" />
  </div>
  <div className="four wide cloumn">
    <img src="/images/home/prof.svg" />
    <div className="solucao-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsom</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="four wide column">
    <img src="/images/home/pais.svg" />
    <div className="solucao-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsom</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="four wide column">
    <img src="/images/home/escola.svg" />
    <div className="solucao-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsom</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The first part is just under the body tag, the second one is under an other div.

Even when I tried loading the same first code on the place of the second one, it doesn't render properly.